# Using AND OR operators in an ADODB Recordset Filter

Tags: adodb, recordset

I am populating a recordset from an Oracle database using vb6.0

From another table I am building a FilterString as below:

```
    While rsInvFilter.EOF = False
        If strResult = "" Then
            strResult = "invtype=" & "'" & rsInvFilter!Inv_Type & "'"
        Else
            strResult = strResult & " or invtype=" & "'" & rsInvFilter!Inv_Type & "'"
        End If
        
        rsInvFilter.MoveNext
    
    Wend
    
    strResult = "(" & strResult & ") and " & "(CoCode='" & strCo_Code & "')"
```

I then use strResult to apply filter to my First Recordset as

```
rsMain.filter=strResult
```

Here I get an error:

> Run-time error 3001
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or in conflict with one another.

If I run `rsMain.Filter="cocode='01'"`, this line works.

If I run `rsMain.Filter="invtype='BC' or invtype='BEX' or invtype='BK' or invtype='JC' or invtype='JEX' or invtype='JK'"`, this line works fine.

But if I run

```
rsMain.Filter = "cocode='01' and (invtype='BC' or invtype='BEX' or invtype='BK' or invtype='JC' or invtype='JEX' or invtype='JK')"
```

I get an error.

Comment: Solved the problem with the help of this:-

[link] (http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/ado_recordset_object_filter_property.htm)

Comment: Hi dandy! You can write your solution as an answer to help others who may have a similar problem.

Comment: This is how I solved it.

My original Filter statement read:-

[code]
rsMain.Filter = "cocode='01' and (invtype='BC' or invtype='BEX' or invtype='BK' or invtype='JC' or invtype='JEX' or invtype='JK')"


I changed it like this:-


[code]
rsMain.Filter = "(cocode='01' and invtype='BC') 
or (cocode='01' and invtype='BEX)' 
or (cocode='01' and invtype='BK') 
or (cocode='01' and invtype='JC') 
or (cocode='01' and invtype='JEX')  
or (cocode='01' and invtype='JK')"

@soundflix... Thank you for suggesting that I explain in detail.